# Infinite loop in exiting a thread using thread pool

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading

I'm working in a code that employ multithreading. The concerned piece of code is in the following structure:

```
try {
    ExecutorService threadExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

    while (resultSet.next()) {
        name = resultSet.getString("hName");
        MyRunnable worker = new Myrunnable(name);
        threadExecutor.execute(worker);
        Counter++;
    }

    //This never appears
    System.out.println("End while with counter" + Counter);

    threadExecutor.shutdown();
    System.out.println("thread shutdown"); //this never appears

    // Wait until all threads are finish
    while (!threadExecutor.isTerminated()) {
        threadExecutor.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        System.out.println("inside the thread termination loop."); //I have infinite loop

    }

    System.out.println("Finished all threads"); //never appears

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

System.out.println("END MAIN");

DBConnection.con.close();
```

The run function ends for sure. The last name in my DB executes the required function and its thread ends.

```
//The constructor
MyRunnable (String name)  {
    this.name=name;
}

public void run() {
    myclass Obj=new myclass();
    try {
        Obj.myFunction(name);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Got an Exception: "+e.getMessage());
    }
    System.out.println(" thread exiting" + this.name);
}
```

My problem is that my program executes everything correctly except that at the last thread, I see the "thread exiting" with the the last name from the DB. But the threadexecutor never shuts down and the program enters an infinite loop.

**EDIT**

Here is the code in the main that extracts names from the DB.

```
try {
        st = DBConnection.con.createStatement();

        resultSet = st.executeQuery("select hName from schema1.table1  where checked=1 order by hName");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("DB Error: " + e.getMessage());

    }
```

Comment: You say that the message `End while resultse with counter` never appears. So your program never exits the `while` loop. Then it doesn't sound like an `ExecutorService`-related problem.

Comment: Plz note that the threads ends and the program terminates if I read small number of records from the DB. But when the number increases, the program never terminates (or at least stay in the loop for long time (+5 min) until I terminate it manually)

Comment: Then it might have to do with what `Obj.myFunction(name)` is doing - if it never ends, and your resultset has more than 10 records (size of your pool), the while loop will never end either.

Comment: So your tasks are waiting in the queue for the earlier tasks to complete, but that never happens?

Comment: I suggest you post a [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: @assylias OP claims that he sees the `thread exiting` message for all rows involved; I think wee need to dispute that claim.

Comment: @assylias: Yes, as I said, the message: System.out.println(" thread exiting" + this.name); which is inside run() appears for all records. Again, the program works fine for small number of records, or with single thread.

Comment: @JuryA Have you tried adding a print statement at the beginning and at the end of the while loop to see if it gets stuck in between?

Comment: Have you tried to use `threadExecutor.submit(worker)` instead of `threadExecutor.execute(worker)`?

Comment: I noticed that the program prints the `System.out.println("End while with counter" + Counter);` This message prints first and with the correct total number of record, then output of the execution of each record appears. I'm not sure if this is the correct thing to happen, it seems like the program executes the while loop first, then executes the threads ?? However, execution the threads ends under certain conditions (if I reduced the no. of records), but it stays for long in the actual DB. I wait for around 500 sec. and I considered this infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my best guess at what's going on:

First off, I suspect that these two comments:

```
//This never appears
System.out.println("End while with counter" + Counter);

threadExecutor.shutdown();
System.out.println("thread shutdown"); //this never appears
```

are incorrect. I strongly suspect that in fact you do get those messages, but they're mixed in with your other messages (such as the "thread exiting" message) so you miss them.

Secondly, I suspect that sometimes, `Obj.myfunction(name)` hangs. This is especially likely if `Obj.myfunction` involves writing back to the database - it'll work correctly most of the time, but every now and then (and more likely with more rows) you'll hit a database deadlock. So, in fact, you aren't getting the "Thread exited" message for *every* name, but finding the one or two in the middle of the list that don't give you that message is going to be difficult.

To determine if this is the case, I would generate a thread dump of your java program while it's sitting in the infinite loop. On Unix/Mac, you do this by opening up another window and doing `kill -3 PID`, where `PID` is the process ID of your java process. In Windows, I think that the key combination you need to use is Ctrl-Break. In the tread dump, look to see if the threadpool's worker threads are stuck inside the call to `Obj.myfunction`.

One possible source of the database deadlock is that you don't close your `ResultSet` until you close the database connection itself at the end of the program. I would add a call to

```
resultSet.close();
```

right after your `while` loop ends, and just before you print out your message about `"End while with counter"`. If you still see database deadlocks happening even after you add that statement, then you'll have to ask a different question focused on what that function `myfunction` is doing.

Comment: For the database, I synchronize the query: 
`Query= " insert into table values (default,?,?)` and the prepared statement: `preparedStmt = DBConnection.con.prepareStatement(Query);` But I do not synchronize the insert and execute: `preparedStmt.setString (1, token);` and   `preparedStmt.executeUpdate();`. Do you see any problem in this ?

Comment: I don't think you understand quite what might be causing database lock-ups, but if what you're calling in the worker threads is writing to the *same table* you're selecting from initially, then you _really_ want to close your `resultSet` as soon as the while loop finishes.

Comment: No. I'm not writing to the same table. They are 2 different tables. My previous question was general as I have doubt in this point from the first place. I will try closing the result set and update you soon.

Comment: I tried closing the resultSet but it does not seems to be the problem. For the thread dump, the problem is that I can not do this through eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Your last comment makes more sense: when you run `executor.execute(..)` it does not mean that the thread is going to be run immediately, and even if it is started immediately, it will not print the "thread exiting" message until it completes. Meanwhile, the main thread goes on and will:

- print `System.out.println("End while with counter" + Counter);`
- run the `threadExecutor.shutdown();` which should return almost immediately
- print `System.out.println("thread shutdown");` almost immediately too.

In other words, if whatever your threads are doing takes a little bit of time, those 2 lines will be printed before any of the threads has finished their tasks.

Now if you program does not exit, it is most likely, as already commented, because of what `Obj.myFunction(name)` is doing - if that calls never ends for some reason, and your resultset has more records than the size of your thread pool, the `while (!threadExecutor.isTerminated())` loop will never end either.

Comment: So, does this means, I have to set the size of thread pool to the records number? Ex: If I have 1000 records, I should set my pool size to 1000 ??

Comment: No it means you have to understand what prevents your threads from exiting and fix it. Daniel Martin put a few ideas in his answer. We can't really help more without more information. Once again, if you manage to create a SSCCE that reproduces the behaviour, it will be much easier to figure out what the problem is.

Comment: The function does SSL handshake. The program does not suffer from problems in single thread mode. I made sure that the function ends. Now, one more question please. If I want to print out the value of `name` in the loop that prints `System.out.println("inside the thread termination loop.");`. How can I do this? When I printed the variable `worker.name` which I assume will give me the value of `name` for this particular thread which is inside the loop, but I always get the last `name` in retrieved from the DB.

Comment: You have not mention that I should see: `System.out.println("inside the thread termination loop.");` during the program execution? I'm not sure if I'm on the right way? This statement appears during execution, and I need is to know which thread is inside the loop. As in my previous comment, I'm trying to print the variable `name`.

Comment: @JuryA You seem to be a little confused about threads here. The thread that runs that while loop is the main thread and name has the last value that was assign to it in that part of code, which is the last name you retrieved from the DB.

Comment: You are right. The loop should make sure that all threads ended before ending the main. What do you suspect if I tell you that the statement inside the loop is printing along the run. Some times for 120 seconds and some times just 2 or 3 lines.

Comment: I suspect that whatever you are doing in your other threads is taking more or less time. If it's a DB connection, there are many factors that can make a connection / query slow.

Comment: One mistake that I'm doing (if the source http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaConcurrency/article.html is correct) is that I'm defining  MyRunnable worker = new Myrunnable(name); while it should be Runnable worker = new Myrunnable(name); . Correct me if the source is wrong. @assylias: The waiting loop print out statement supposed to appear once only as it is in the main ??

Comment: Assuming MyRunnable is a Runnable, that does not make a difference with regards to your issue. Sorry to insist, but until you post a working example that demonstrates your problem (i.e. I can copy paste it and run it as is on my machine), it will be difficult to help you further.

Comment: If this is possible, I will. There is DB connected with it. In addition, I might not have the right to post it.

Comment: It does not have to be all the code, but at least all the relevant code. Ideally, you could try to recreate a similar example that has the same problem. But for sure: don't post code that you don't own!